# Grab IP addresses only by pinging list of server names using Batch

Tags: batch-file, ping, findstr

I have a text file containing a list of a few hundred server names

```
Server1

Server2

Server3

Server4
```

and so on...

I want to run a batch file which will take this file , ping all of them and return just the IP address if found, or "DOWN" if unreachable or not found. I want the output to go into output.txt, and the output only needs to be the IP address or "DOWN".

Sample output:

```
176.28.29.100

DOWN

176.28.29.105

176.28.29.110
```

Edit: I am new to batch and so far I have done this: Throw servernames into excel, get this in another column for the number of servernames

```
ping -n 1 servername | findstr "Pinging host" >> out.txt
```

...

The output I get is in the form

```
Ping request could not find host Server1. Please check the name and try again.

Pinging Sever2 [176.28.29.105] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 176.28.29.110: Destination host unreachable.
```

Want to get just the IPs

Comment: Can you edit your post and show us what did you tried so far as code ?

Comment: Added details. I am looking for a better way to get this done.

Comment: If the only thing you want is the IP addresses, why use `ping`?  Why not `nslookup`?

Comment: @RyanBemrose: the question says: " if unreachable or not found". `ping` is for the "unreachable" part. And `nslookup` may be a bit ugly for parsing (see for example `nslookup www.yahoo.com`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to process a file line by line, use `for /f`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%i in (servers.txt) do (
  set p=DOWN
  set r=no response
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%p in ('ping -n 1 -w 1 %%i^|find "["' ) do set p=%%p
  ping -n 1 -w 2000 %%i|find "TTL" >nul && set r=running
  echo %%i  is !p! !r!
)
```

(adapt the `echo` line to your needs)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (server.txt) do (
  set "$ip="
  for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%b in ('ping -n 1 %%a ^| find "["') do (
   set "$ip=%%b"
  )
   if defined $ip (echo %%a - !$ip! OK) else (echo %%a KO) 
)
```

Comment: that's like my first approach: it tells, if there is a DNS-Resolution, but not if there is a response.